# Echo HTML code, which is retrieved from a external page in php

Tags: php, html

We have this code

```php
$page = file_get_contents('http://example.aspx?a=14&c=14213&med=0');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the table´s looking for one withan id of "Table2"
    // Then echo out its contents
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'Table2') {
         echo $div->childNodes;
    }
}
```

As you see the code works, but outputs plain text, because the function of childnodes, but we need to output the code of "Table2" instead of plain text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, with this code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
            $data = file_get_contents('http://example.aspx?a=14&c=14213&med=0');
            $dom->loadHTML($data); // $data is your html code, grab it using file_get_contents or cURL.
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $div = $xpath->query('//table[@id="Table2"]');
            $div = $div->item(0);
            echo $dom->saveXML($div);
```